# adding effect strip using script

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor

I'm trying to construct a script to step through the active scene and:

1) find all the movie strips that the audio doesn't match the corresponding movie length

2) then add > effect strip > speed control to the movie strips that the, corresponding audio strip's frame length doesn't match.

3) not sure if this is possible, but would be nice to make the speed strip the same length of the audio strip. I think it would need to space out all the strips to give the script room to increase the movie strips length without bumping into the next strip along.

This is what I have so far, not sure why it doesn't work.

```
import bpy

for a in bpy.context.scene.sequence_editor.sequences:
    if a.type != 'SOUND':
        a.effect_strip_add(type='SPEED')
```

Answer (score 2):

The type [Sequences](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_4/bpy.types.Sequences.html) does not contain `effect_strip_add` , that's part of the sequences operators(bpy.ops). The correct way to add a strip(i.e. effect) is by using:

```
sequences.new_effect(name, type, channel, frame_start, frame_end=0, seq1=None, seq2=None, seq3=None)
```